# Text describing different stages inside a progress bar - Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

Is there a tweak (or available plugin) to show text inside a progress bar? This text is to show what stage an order is at. Plus, I want to show call-out div right at the current value of the progress bar.

Please see an attached image.
[image: something like]

or something like [this progress bar](https://www.zocdoc.com/booking/start?startTime=634838256000000000&professionalId=41297&locationId=29436&specialtyId=345&procedureId=1296&referrerType=&repeatPatient=false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **HTML**

```
<input id="upload" type="button" value="Upload" />
<br/>
<div id="pb1">
    <div id="percent1">Order Taken | In processing | Order Shipped | order Delivered</div>
```

## **jQuery**

```
$('#upload').click(function () {
    //$('#pb').progressbar();
    //$('#pb').progressbar({value:50});
    var val = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        val++;
        $('#pb1').progressbar({
            value: val,
            change: function () {
                $('#percent1').css('display', 'block');
            },
            complete: function () {}
        });
        if (val == 100) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 50);
});
```

## **CSS**

```
body {
    font-size:12px;
}
#pb, #pb1 {
    width:450px;
}
#percent, #percent1 {
    display:none;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
}
```

Working DeMO http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/NvZTs/

Comment: it works! Many thanks. Is there a way I can find the position of the progress bar where it stops? I have my call out div ready. I just have to place it at the right place (right above where progress bar stops).